# No module named 'transformers.models.bark.configuration_bark'

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition, spacy-transformers

I am trying to import spacy's `"en_core_web_trf"` model in Colab and facing error because it " Failed to import transformers.models.bark.configuration_bark". What do i do to resolve this?

Here's what i did:

```
import spacy.cli
import spacy_transformers
spacy.cli.download("en_core_web_trf")

NER = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
```

Here's what I got:

```
✔ Download and installation successful
You can now load the package via spacy.load('en_core_web_trf')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py in _get_module(self, module_name)

26 frames
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'transformers.models.bark.configuration_bark'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py in _get_module(self, module_name)

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.models.bark.configuration_bark because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
No module named 'transformers.models.bark.configuration_bark'
```

Comment: `pip install --upgrade transformers==4.30.2` fixed it for me